# How to fix a parent for an entity?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Basically, when I put a text box, using Blend or Drag and Drop option of visual studios, the text box makes it's margin with respect to some other entity already present in the view, so I want to know whether I can change that entity and if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

### Assign to other parent

You can simply drag the child element in the to a different parent:

In Blend: in the "Objects and Timeline" view; the UI will inform you which parent it will be added to (and hit Alt to select a parent)

In Visual Studio: just drag it.

In both cases the designer will update the margins to keep the control where you dropped it.

### If you want to reset margins

In Blend: click the tiny boxes next to the property you want to reset and select reset.

In Visual Studio: right-click the control and select "Reset Layout".